# Spring и thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

[image: ошибка]Хочу вывести значения базы данных на страницу ввиде таблицы id, name, email, не получается. Кто знает, скажите как сделать правильно, потому что выдает ошибку.

add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul th:object="${users}">
            <li>ID: <span th:text="*{id}">id</span></li>
            <li>Name: <span th:text="*{name}">name</span></li>
            <li>Address : <span th:text="*{email}">email</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p><a href="/">home</a></p>
</body>
</html
```

Контроллер

```
   @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public String getAllUsers(Map<String,Object> model) {
        Iterable <User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        model.put("users",users);
        return "all";
    }
```

Класс User

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса подробности об ошибке.

Comment: добавил ошибку.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов тут без ошибки видно в чем проблема)

Comment: Ваша проблема решилась?

Comment: да,  проблема решилась

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки на оригинал ответа:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744655/for-each-operator-in-thymeleaf

```html
<div th:each="user : ${users}">
   <ul>
       <li>ID: <span th:text="*{user.id}">id</span></li>
       <li>Name: <span th:text="*{user.name}">name</span></li>
       <li>Address : <span th:text="*{user.email}">email</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Кстати, рассмотри для удобства записи getters/setters, constructors - [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org)